# How to check if condition in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to check in my stored procedure that if my RawMaterialStock table column RawMaterial Id is equal to my procedure argument @RawMaterialId

I am doing this.

```
if(dbo.[RawMaterialStock].RawMaterialId=@RawMaterialId)
   BEGIN
    Update [RawMaterialStock] 
    set 
    Quantity=Quantity+ @TotalQty
    end
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[RawMaterialStock]
    ([RawMaterialId],Quantity) 
    VALUES
    (@RawMaterialId,@TotalQty)
end
```

But it is giving error Multipair Identifier could not be bound.
How can I check this condition, I am a Beginner Programmer please explain simply.

Comment: You need to provide the exact error message and indicate where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a merge.
Something like this:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[RawMaterialStock] AS Target
USING (
    VALUES (@RawMaterialId, @TotalQty)
    ) AS Source (NewRawMaterialId, NewQuantity)
    ON  target.[RawMaterialId] = source.NewRawMaterialId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Quantity = Source.NewQuantity + Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([RawMaterialId],Quantity) VALUES (source.NewRawMaterialID, source.NewQuantity);
```

Comment: No problem dude. Mark the answer as accepted please, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this:

```
if(dbo.[RawMaterialStock].RawMaterialId=@RawMaterialId)
BEGIN
    --Stuff
END
```

Instead, you have to select the data out of the table into its own variable.

```
DECLARE @Tmp int
SELECT @Tmp = dbo.[RawMaterialStock].RawMaterialId

IF (@Tmp = @RawMaterialId)
BEGIN
    --Stuff
END
```

Or do something clever like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM dbo.[RawMaterialStock] WHERE RawMaterialId = @RawMaterialId)
BEGIN
    --Stuff
END
```

Comment: thnx for replying. i used the merge statement and it works.